# Will the software center offer an option to donate?

Tags: software-center

Will the software center offer an option to donate to the developer/s of a particular application?

Comment: Good idea, +1 for Software Center Donation buttons! :) But, I think it should be a launchpad feature. For example, you add a launchpad ppa to the software center, and the donation buttons appear.

Comment: I am 99% sure that this was actually planned for 11.04, but it looks like the devs did not have enough time to implement it. Don't have any sources though, so I'll not post an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature is planned for [11.10](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter#October%202011):

> **October 2011**
>
> We plan to implement donations for non-commercial software projects.

Comment: Didn't happen, AFAIK. Maybe in 12.04...?

Comment: There is information available on 

[https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-donations-for-free-software-through-software-center][1]

and 

[https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareDonations][2]




  [1]: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/packageselection-desktop-n-donations-for-free-software-through-software-center
  [2]: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareDonations